# Hive UDF String to Date Convertion

Tags: date, hadoop, casting, hive

The Hive contains a table "sample" with the following data:

```
15-06-2015
15-06-2015
15-06-2015
15-06-2015
15-06-2015
15-06-2015
16-06-2015
```

Using the following query i am converting String type of data into Hive Date format:

```
select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date,'DD-MM-YYYY'))) from sample;
```

The output as follows:

```
0   2014-12-28
1   2014-12-28
2   2014-12-28
3   2014-12-28
4   2014-12-28
5   2014-12-28
6   2014-12-28
```

The output is differ from expected output.

Please suggest how to get the expected output like:

```
2015-06-15
2015-06-15
2015-06-15
2015-06-15
2015-06-15
2015-06-15
2015-06-16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that HiveQL is generally case insensitive, but the second argument of the `unix_timestamp` function, instead, is **case sensitive**. Thus the right syntax for your query is:

```
select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date,'dd-MM-yyyy'))) from sample;
```

In this way, you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Thanking you. I got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply a typo, the pattern should be `dd-MM-yyyy`.